# R - calculating overlap between two ellipses

Tags: r, graph

First things first, yes, there have been similar questions asked here previously. However, they all stem from PCA or from some specialized packages; it's visible in the data that these people provided in the question that this data doesn't match the case that I have and I cannot use it.

I have a dataset literally with the centroids, major and minor axes, and angles of the ellipse. Here is a very minimal example:

```
data <- data.frame(x0 = c(0, 0), y0 = c(0, 0), a = c(5, 3), b = c(10, 20), angle = c(45, 35), Ellipse = c("Ell1", "Ell2"))
```

The dataframe:

```
  x0 y0 a  b angle Ellipse
1  0  0 5 10    45    Ell1
2  0  0 3 20    35    Ell2
```

I also display it visually, just for didactic purposes (I ***don't*** need to plot the overlapping area):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggforce)

ggplot(data, aes(x0 = x0, 
                 y0 = y0,
                 a = a, 
                 b = b, 
                 angle = angle, 
                 color = Ellipse)) + 
  geom_ellipse()
```

[image]

Given this setup, how can I calculate the overlapping area?

Comment: Googling "overlap ellipses" provides some results but there's nothing easy.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent yes, an exact mathematical form seems too difficult. Much easier to create the ellipses as polygons and use `sf` to get a close estimate of their overlap.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The math for an exact solution is very difficult here. I think the easiest way to do this in R is to create your ellipses as polygons and use the `sf` library to get their intersection. It is then very easy to get its area.

The most difficult part is creating your ellipses from the given parameters, but the following function should do the trick:

```r
make_ellipse <- function(x0, y0, a, b, angle) {
  angle <- angle/360 * 2 * pi
  theta <- c(seq(0, 2 * pi, length.out = 360), 0)

  crds <- cbind(a * cos(theta) * cos(angle) - b * sin(theta) * sin(angle) + x0,
                a * cos(theta) * sin(angle) + b * sin(theta) * cos(angle) + y0)
  sf::st_polygon(list(crds))
}
```

This allows us to use your data frame to get the ellipses as follows:

```r
a <- do.call(make_ellipse, data[1, 1:5])
b <- do.call(make_ellipse, data[2, 1:5])
```

And we can see that these are correct by doing:

```r
plot(b)
plot(a, add = TRUE)
```

[image]

We can get the intersection as follows:

```r
intersection <- sf::st_intersection(a, b)
```

Again, we can see this is correct by adding it to our plot:

```r
plot(intersection, add = TRUE, col = 'red')
```

[image]

And since we are satisfied that the red intersection is indeed the shape whose area we are interested in, we can simply do:

```r
sf::st_area(intersection)
#> [1] 105.3689
```

Comment: Nice -- worth noting that `st_area` appears to perform the integration even when the boundary sections  may not be 1:1 functions.

Comment: Two notes: 1) It's not clear without a lot of digging what the error is in `sf` function calculations, so depending on the OP's real needs, this may or may not be accurate enough.   2)  Might be worth warning folks that `sf` and `s2` will calculate stuff on the surface of a sphere if you aren't careful **not** to specify 3 dimensions.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft thanks - these are reasonable points. I _think_ the error can be minimised arbitrarily by increasing the number of points calculated around the perimeter of the ellipse. Also, the function in this answer by design returns simple planar polygons which do not have an associated projection to complicate matters in 3D space.

Comment: Allan, please take a look at my answer. I found an example we can compare with (in my edit). Could you try it with your method?

Comment: @AllanCameron  I appreciate your response.  Makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 4):

This is the same method as @Allan but using different packages: **PlaneGeometry** to deal with the two ellipses, and **cgalPolygons** (not on CRAN) to compute their intersection and the area. Good news: one finds almost the same result.

```r
library(PlaneGeometry)
library(cgalPolygons)

ell1 <- Ellipse$new(center = c(0, 0), rmajor = 10, rminor = 5, alpha = 45)
ell2 <- Ellipse$new(center = c(0, 0), rmajor = 20, rminor = 3, alpha = 35)

ell1_path <- ell1$path(npoints = 200L)
ell2_path <- ell2$path(npoints = 200L)

ell1_polygon <- cgalPolygonWithHoles$new(ell1_path)
ell2_polygon <- cgalPolygonWithHoles$new(ell2_path)

# intersection
interList <- ell1_polygon$intersection(ell2_polygon)
inter <- interList[[1]]

# plot
opar <- par(mar = c(0, 0, 0, 0))
plot(
  NULL, xlim = c(-26, 26), ylim = c(-16, 16), asp = 1, 
  xlab = NA, ylab = NA, axes = FALSE
)
ell1_polygon$plot(list(lwd = 2), lwd = 2, density = 10, new = FALSE)
ell2_polygon$plot(list(lwd = 2), lwd = 2, density = 10, new = FALSE)
inter$plot(lwd = 4, col = "red", new = FALSE)
par(opar)

# area
inter$area()
# 105.357
```

[image]

---

## Edit: ellipse partitioning

We can also split an ellipse and check if its area is close to the sum of the areas of its parts.

```r
library(PlaneGeometry)
library(cgalPolygons)

# first ellipse
ell1 <- Ellipse$new(center = c(0, 0), rmajor = 10, rminor = 5, alpha = 45)
# second ellipse
ell2 <- Ellipse$new(center = c(0, 0), rmajor = 20, rminor = 3, alpha = 35)

# first ellipse as a path (2-columns matrix)
ell1_path <- ell1$path(npoints = 500L)
# second ellipse as a parh
ell2_path <- ell2$path(npoints = 500L)

# convert to polygons 
ell1_polygon <- cgalPolygonWithHoles$new(ell1_path)
ell2_polygon <- cgalPolygonWithHoles$new(ell2_path)

# intersection
ell12_polygon <- ell1_polygon$intersection(ell2_polygon)
# the intersection is a single polygon
ell12_polygon <- ell12_polygon[[1L]]

# plot the two ellipses and their intersection
opar <- par(mar = c(0, 0, 0, 0))
plot(
  NULL, xlim = c(-26, 26), ylim = c(-16, 16), asp = 1, 
  xlab = NA, ylab = NA, axes = FALSE
)
ell1_polygon$plot(list(lwd = 2), lwd = 2, new = FALSE)
ell2_polygon$plot(list(lwd = 2), lwd = 2, new = FALSE)
ell12_polygon$plot(lwd = 4, col = "red", new = FALSE)
par(opar)
```

[image]

```r
# now subtract ell2 to ell1
subtraction_ell1_minus_ell2 <- ell1_polygon$subtract(ell2_polygon)
# this gives two polygons
plgn1 <- subtraction_ell1_minus_ell2[[1L]]
plgn2 <- subtraction_ell1_minus_ell2[[2L]]

# let's plot ell1 and its partition into three parts
opar <- par(mar = c(2, 2, 1, 1))
plot(
  NULL, xlim = c(-16, 16), ylim = c(-10, 10), asp = 1, 
  xlab = NA, ylab = NA, axes = FALSE
)
axis(1); axis(2)
# ellipse 1
ell1_polygon$plot(list(lwd = 2), lwd = 2, new = FALSE)
# ellipse 1 inter ellipse 2
ell12_polygon$plot(lwd = 2, col = "red", new = FALSE)
# the first piece of the subtraction
plgn1$plot(lwd = 2, col = "green", new = FALSE)
# the second piece of the subtraction
plgn2$plot(lwd = 2, col = "blue", new = FALSE)
par(opar)

# green area
garea <- plgn1$area()
# blue area
barea <- plgn2$area()
# red area
rarea <- ell12_polygon$area()

# sum of the three areas
garea + barea + rarea
# = 157.0755

# area of ellipse 1 (pi * major * minor)
pi * ell1$rmajor * ell1$rminor
# = 157.0796
```

[image]

The sum of the three areas is slightly less than the true area of the ellipse. That's normal because the paths we take approximate the true paths from below.

---

## Edit: comparison with an "exact" result

There's an implementation on [this Github repo](https://github.com/chraibi/EEOver). Here is an example treated with this implementation:

[image]

The resulting area is `A12` and `epsilon` is the relative error.

I tried with my method. Here are the parameters:

```r
ell1 <- Ellipse$new(
  center = c(14.527050, 8.343243), rmajor = 5.262357, rminor = 4.555325, alpha = -2.933767, degrees = FALSE
)
ell2 <- Ellipse$new(
  center = c(7.598473,  6.096601), rmajor = 6.720221, rminor = 5.767499, alpha = -1.624, degrees = FALSE
)
```

Then proceeding as above, taking 500 points to approximate the ellipses, I find `21.44292`, very close to `A12`.